# Sample random element from two lists where value = 1

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `cluster0Y` and `clusterY` which are made up of 1's and 0's. Eg.

```
cluster0Y = [0,1,0,0,1]
cluster1Y = [0,0,0,1]
```

I want to randomly sample 1 element from the lists cluster0Y and cluster1Y where the value is 1. I then want to print the list which it belongs to and print the index. To do this I wrote the following code:

```
from random import randrange
cluster0Y = [0,1,0,1]
cluster1Y = [0,1,0,1]
while True:
        random_index = randrange(0,len(cluster0Y+cluster1Y))
        print(str(random_index))
        if random_index > len(cluster0Y):
            random_index = random_index - len(cluster0Y)
            if cluster1Y[random_index]==1:
                print('cluster 1 ' + str(random_index))
                break
        else:
            if cluster0Y[random_index]==1:
                print('cluster 0 ' + str(random_index))
                break
        print(str(random_index))
```

However, this code sometimes prints out values which aren't 1 in the lists. Why is this the case?

Comment: Do you want to sample from both of them or just one of the lists?

Comment: @yklsga randomly sample 1 element from both lists (ie. equal probability from either list if each list has the same number of elements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely *picking* values which are not 1, but not printing them. You're printing the random indices that are pointing at non-1 values.

You can also rethink your logic so it looks more like

```
extract the indices of 1 values in list0
extract the indices of 1 values in list1
pick a random option from the extracted indices
```

Something along the lines of:

```
allOnes0 = [(ind, 0) for ind, v in enumerate(cluster0Y) if v == 1]
allOnes1 = [(ind, 1) for ind, v in enumerate(cluster1Y) if v == 1]
(index, clusterId) = random.choice(allOnes0 + allOnes1)
```

Where `clusterId` tells you whether the random 1 came from cluster 0 or 1, and `index` tells you the position of the 1 in the cluster.

Which is a lot more straightforward and a lot less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected here, but you have to fix an off-by-one error:

```
if random_index > len(cluster0Y):
```

.. this will fail a read from cluster0Y later if the random_index is exactly len(cluster0Y) in size.

```
if random_index >= len(cluster0Y):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code here is too convoluted for what you are trying to achieve.

You can use something like `[idx for idx, val in enumerate(cluster) if val != 0]` to find the indices of non zero elements and go from there.

As for why it prints 0s some times, I think that @MatsLindh found the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit. I changed it to `>=` because according to your code when `random_index = 4`, it won't satisfy the condition `random_index > len(cluster0Y)` and there by you will get an list out of range error

```
from random import randrange
cluster0Y = [0,1,0,1]
cluster1Y = [0,1,0,1]
while True:
        random_index = randrange(0,len(cluster0Y+cluster1Y))
        if random_index >= len(cluster0Y):
            random_index = random_index - len(cluster0Y)
        if cluster1Y[random_index]==1:
            print('cluster 1 : ',random_index)
            break
        if cluster0Y[random_index]==1:
            print('cluster 0 : ',random_index)
            break
        print('random index = ',random_index)
```